# Mod rewrite - redirecting url with certain parameter to new url

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I need some help redirecting a url with particular parameter value to a new url. For example how can i redirect these two urls with id 123 and 345 to a new url?

Redirect

- `http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=123`
- `http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=345`

to

- `https://newpage.silkroad.com/`

Comment: Have a look at this [intro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) on mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect, then put the following in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks        # Must be enabled if not already
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc/content/content\.jsp\?contentId=(123|345)$ https://newpage.silkroad.com/ [R=301,L]
```